# how to change the name of each select value in the following program

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have problem in this code of drop down list LINK:([When i add more dropdown boxes, javascript is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074840/when-i-add-more-dropdown-boxes-javascript-is-not-working?newreg=fbf5865e79d14c66bb6990bd15be7d35)). I need an help please can you change the `select name=""`of each so that I can call all the values in php. Please help me out as soon as possible.

Comment: You want to add a list dynamically to the page or ad an element to an already existing list?

Comment: i just want the names of each field different so that i can call it in php easily @Osuwariboy.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the code you have too much, why not go with something like this in your add function:

```
function add(tbl1) 
{
    var tb = document.getElementById(tbl1);
    var rowCount = tb.rows.length;
    var row = tb.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = tb.rows[1].cells.length;
    var newName = "car_" + rowCount;


    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) 
    {
        var newCell = row.insertCell(i);
        var cellTemp = tb.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;

        if(cellTemp.indexOf("select") > -1)
            cellTemp.replace("car_1", newName);

        newCell.innerHTML = cellTemp;
    }
}
```

And then in HTML, your select controls would change slightly, like this:

```
<select name=car_1[] id="cat">
    <option value="Dals">Dals</option>
    <option value = "Flour">Flour</option>
</select>

<select name=car_2[] id="item"></select>
```

Comment: thank u but i am little confused can  u please paste the whole code i am a little weak in javascript.